# UIKitDynamics when working with Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation, uikit-dynamics

I want to add animations to some buttons using UIKitDynamics, however doing the very very basics with a UISnapBehaviour doesn't work at all. I am using IB to layout all of my subviews, so keep in mind that I cannot reposition anything by calling self.button.frame, you have to use constraints.

That said here is what I have...When I run the animation it blinks quickly and looks terrible.

```
// Position the buttons off screen
        self.swerveButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self.followButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self.swerveButtonTopSpaceConstraint.constant = -200;

        CGPoint swerveSnapPoint = self.swerveButton.center;
        CGPoint followSnapPoint = self.followButton.center;

        UISnapBehavior *followSnap = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self.followButton
                                                              snapToPoint:followSnapPoint];

        UISnapBehavior *swerveSnap = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self.swerveButton
                                                              snapToPoint:swerveSnapPoint];


        [self.overlayView fadeInWithDuration:0.2 completion:^{
            swerveSnap.damping = 0.3;
            [self.animator addBehavior:swerveSnap];

            followSnap.damping = 0.3;
            [self.animator addBehavior:followSnap];
        }];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

UIKitDynamics doesn't work with constraints. If you want to use them you'll have to go old school and set frames manually, at least during the animation anyway.

Comment: I found a work around, if you create a custom object to act as the dynamic item, you can change the constraints in the action block of say a UISnapBehaviour. It worked great.